# How to distribute cards until the entire card stack/pack is distributed based on shuffling/random numbers, with a click of a button?

Tags: objective-c, random, shuffle, arc4random, playing-cards

I am creating my first card game, and need to shuffle the cards. So for starters, I have created a shuffle button for a sample stack of 4 values with the line:

```
int i = arc4random() % 4;
NSLog(@"%d", i);
```

Shuffling works well, but I want this button to allow the user to distribute random cards until there are no more cards in the stack. Each time I click this sample button, I need `NSLoged` result to be something like 3, then 1, then 0, then 2, then "No more cards", for example (instead of a list of four random numbers and a message).

Is there a simple way to "distribute a number" randomly with each click of a button?

Also, does `arc4random` generate real random numbers or pseudo-random numbers? I have read a lot of threads about it, and it doesn't seem so clear. What would be the best way to randomize numbers?

Comment: You should probably put somewhere the language you are using. In this case I'm assuming its objective-C but a tag would be a good place to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an array with all the possible elements in the random space, for example:

```
NSMutableArray *randomNumber = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[NSNumber numberWithInt:0], [NSNumber numberWithInt:1],[NSNumber numberWithInt:2],[NSNumber numberWithInt:3], nil];
```

Then, you take randomly elements of the array, and you remove them after:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){

int randIndex = arc4random()%[randomNumber count];
NSLog(@" %d %d", randIndex, [[randomNumber objectAtIndex:randIndex] intValue]);
[randomNumber removeObjectAtIndex:randIndex];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have tried this code, and each time I click the Shuffle button, NSLog now gives me a list of four pairs of numbers. Let's see if I have this right:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know clicking the Enter key would post my comment. Just give me a little time to try and understand what's happening with the code.

Comment: I havent tested the code, but it can give you an idea of how to handle this.

Comment: So the first line creates an array populated with integers only. The second line randomizes the number of objects in the array. The third line displays a pair composed of the result and the index value. And the fourth line removes the object (which should mean the array count is now 3). And when I click again on the button, the array is reset and the process begins anew. Am I getting it right?

Comment: OK, I think I am beginning to get it right. I have put the array declaration in ViewDidLoad and the for statement in the button, with an if ([cardsAray count == 1] statement to handle the No More cards message (I might use a "fake index 0 card" for this). I am trying to add a line so that each value is displayed with one click, instead of all four values as a list. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: Just put it out of the for statement, and use global variables